# Android -- Dynamically Adding Items to Gallery Adapter

Tags: android, gallery, adapter

I've seen the use of media scanners to dynamically add items from the sd card to a gallery but I'm in need of adding content from the web.

I have a large quantity of images to display and I want to load 5 to start with and have a "load more" button at the end.  This button will add 5 more images to the end of the gallery and keep the original 5 as well as keep the "load more" button at the end.